How to regex/escape backslash in Debian (Gnome) Text Editor?
In Gnome's Text Editor (gnome-text-editor aka gted from the gnome-text-editor Debian package), I cannot get replacement of starting lines (-) at newlines by \item.

I escape the item but does not work.
OS: Debian latest

You need to double the backslash: \\item (without the quotes).
gnome-text-editor internally uses the GtkSourceView widget which is the one where the search and replace is implemented.
You'll find that a great number of backslash-lead escapes are supported in the replacement such as \1 to expand to the first capture group, \U to change the case of what follows, \t to insert a TAB characters and \\ to insert a literal backslash, similar to what you get in the standard vi text editor, and with a few more extensions, some of which perl-like.
For currently unrecognised escapes such as \i, the widget raises a unknown escape sequence error, but at least in gnome-text-editor 46.1, that doesn't seem to be propagated to the user and the replacement appears to do nothing.

Much of this is also explained in the editor’s online help, but I don’t think there’s a nice web version of that.
